# Setting power BI alert on member joiner and leaver

Tags: powerbi

I would like to create an Alert on my dashboard, the dashboard consist of Member joiners and leaver per region by month and year. I want to create an alert and notify the regional officials . Each Region has target , lets say they need to recruit 10 member per month, So they should get notify when they achieve the target at the same time those who haven't meet the target or recruited below 5 members should also get notify that they haven't meet threshold or they are lacking.

How can i achieve this ? Any suggestion much appreciated.